# Last and Second-to-Last row displaying same 'CurrentRow' index

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my DataBound DataGridView in Winforms C# (bound to DataTable), I'm trying to determine if the user has selected the `NewRow` that is automatically added every time more data is added to the grid. If the `NewRow` is selected, I want to ignore the Delete Row click, however in the below 2 screenshots, `datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index` is returning the same value. Any help is much appreciated!

[image][image]

In both the above cases, `datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index` displayed `1`

I tried using `datagridview1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow` however because the index is showing the same, it obviously doesn't work.

This is the code for the `deleteRow` button

```
private void btnDeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int currentRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index; // TESTING DURING DEBUG, THIS PRODUCES THE SAME VALUE FOR BOTH ROWS PICTURED
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow) return;
        var counter = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
        new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM IncomingVisitorList WHERE Counter = " + counter, SqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch { } // SUPPRESS/IGNORE NULL ROW EXCEPTION
}
```

Comment: where is you code that determines that Selected Row.. how do you have this setup to determine if the CELL or Row or Full ROW has been selected.. can you show you actual code where you are trying to determine the row Index or current row they are on..?

Comment: @MethodMan see update.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is… the code you posted DOES NOT return the same value for the two different rows. I put a message box to display `currentRowIndex` in the posted code and the numbers were NOT the same as you describe. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnG Could it be something to do with the fact that I'm using ComboBox columns???

Comment: A combo box column appears to make no difference… still the row indexes are different. I am curious why you would be concerned about WHICH row index is present…If the selected row IS the NEW row, simply ignore it as the posted code appears to do successfully.

Comment: @JohnG, that's the thing. It doesn't show the selected row as NEW row for some reason. Could be to do with the data binding do you think?

Comment: Here's a video of me during debug mode, testing each row. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhtw8p9cknxc1s2/Untitled.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Even `CurrentCell` displays ColumnIndex 3, RowIndex 1   for both above images.

Comment: You are correct... if the datagridview is data bound these indexes are not returning the correct row index. I will look into this, but I am guessing you may have to get the DataBoundItem for that row. I will get back if someone else does not supply an answer.

Comment: Thanks @JohnG, appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure WHY the `IsNewRow` property is not working as described and I am also not sure WHY the returned index is the same for the new row and the last row with data.

Below is a possible workaround. It appears that if you get the first `int trueRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;` it will return the proper index.

The previous statement will return the same index for the `datagridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex` **UNLESS** it is the new row. The code below is an example of this.

I wish I had a better answer as to WHY, unfortunately this alternative is the only solution I can suggest at this time. I will try to find out why the `IsNewRow` property does not work with DataBound Items. Hope this helps.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    int currentRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int trueRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
    //MessageBox.Show("currentRowIndex " + currentRowIndex + " true row index: " + trueRowIndex);
    if (currentRowIndex != trueRowIndex) {
      MessageBox.Show("Row Is New Row");
    }
    else {
      MessageBox.Show("Row Is not New Row");
      dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
      //new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM IncomingVisitorList WHERE Counter = " + counter, SqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```